# Is there a way to skip the selection of Publication target in Outbound Email?

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email

I am implementing Outbound Email for newsletters in 2013 SP1.

While creating a new mailing it is mandatory to provide the publication target. However, the requirement from client is to reduce the number of steps needed to create and send a mailing.

Just like setting up a page template in a structure group, is it possible to provide a default target in Outbound emails - so that every time website information managers do not require to select the publication target.

I have gone through the Content Manager Explorer User Manual (which includes Audience Manager and Outbound Email) but unable to find out any such configuration.

Please suggest if there is a way to implement the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to pre-select a Publication Target for a Mailing.

You could do it by creating a GUI extension, but this would obviously require development effort from your side.

Comment: Are the visible target options driven by authorization (i.e. is the list the same as the Publishing Queue for a given user)?

Comment: It shows all Publication Targets, as there is no way to limit it (normally only administrators see the list of them). The drop-down list in the Publish Queue is actually showing Target Types (which do have security on them).